# soup.find doesn't find div's class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this page: https://1xbet.cm/en/line/Football/1536237-FIFA-World-Cup-2018/ for it's soccer odds, but I get nothing returned when I try find relevant classes through BeautifulSoup. Can someone explain why I don't find anything?

[image]

```
class GetData():

    def __init__(self, url):

        self.url = url
        r = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    def do_smth(self):

        content = self.soup.find_all("div", class_="bets_content")
        print(content)

url = 'https://1xbet.cm/en/line/Football/1536237-FIFA-World-Cup-2018/'
gd = GetData(url)
gd.do_smth()
```

Comment: Codes should be added as code blocks and not as images. That makes it searchable and readability increases too.

Comment: Use `content = self.soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': "bets_content"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `BeautifulSoup` can't help you to scrape the data from this website because the website uses `VueJS` as a `JavaScript` framewok who consumes the websites API/web services to get the final template.

So, in order to get your data, you can parse directly the APIs/web services and get what you needs.

Here is an example using `requests` and `re` modules:

```
import re
import requests


class GetData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_url = 'https://1xbet.cm/en/line/Football/1536237-FIFA-World-Cup-2018/'
        self.headers = {
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'referer': 'https://1xbet.cm/en/line/Football/1536237-FIFA-World-Cup-2018/',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36'
        }



    def read(self, url):
        with requests.get(url, headers=self.headers) as response:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return response.json()
            else:
                raise Exception('Got error: {}'.format(response.status_code))



    def pretty_print(self, msg, data):
        print(msg + ' :')
        print(data)
        print('#' * 40)



    def get_teams_id(self, url):
        teams_regex = re.findall(r'/(\d+)-', self.main_url)
        if teams_regex:
            teams_id = teams_regex[0]
            return url.format(teams_id)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Cannot parse Teams ID")



    def get_teams_info(self, pretty_print=False):
        teams_url = 'https://1xbet.cm/LineFeed/GetChampTeams?id={}&lng=en'
        valid_url = self.get_teams_id(teams_url)
        data = self.read(valid_url)
        if pretty_print:
            values = data.get('Value', [])
            teams = [values[k:k+2] for k in range(0, len(values), 2)]
            teams_pretty = '\n'.join(' VS '.join(map(
                    lambda x: '{}({})'.format(x.get('N'), x.get('I')), k)
                )  for k in teams
            )
            self.pretty_print('Teams Info', teams_pretty)

        return data



    def get_teams_cotes(self, pretty_print=False):
        cotes_url = 'https://1xbet.cm/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?champs={}&count=50&lng=en&tf=1500000&mode=4'
        valid_url = self.get_teams_id(cotes_url)
        data = self.read(valid_url)
        if pretty_print:
            values = data.get('Value')
            for k in values:
                msg = '{}\n{} VS {}\nCotes: [{}, ..., {}]'.format(
                    k.get('L'),
                    k.get('O1'),
                    k.get('O2'),
                    k.get('E')[0],
                    k.get('E')[-1]
                )
                self.pretty_print('Events & Cotes', msg)

        return data



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GetData()
    _ = app.get_teams_info(pretty_print=True)
    _ = app.get_teams_cotes(pretty_print=True)
```

And if you run this code you'll have a result similar to this one:

```
Teams Info :
Belgium(12609) VS Croatia(12739)
England(12763) VS France(12771)
########################################
Events & Cotes :
FIFA World Cup 2018
France VS Belgium
Cotes: [{'T': 1, 'G': 1, 'C': 2.58}, ..., {'T': 181, 'G': 19, 'C': 2.125}]
########################################
Events & Cotes :
FIFA World Cup 2018
Croatia VS England
Cotes: [{'T': 1, 'G': 1, 'C': 3.64}, ..., {'T': 181, 'G': 19, 'C': 1.805}]
########################################
```

And now it's your turn to parse the data and get what you need. And please be gentle with the website.

Comment: Chiheb thank you so much for taking the time to write this code! If you don't mind me asking, how do you even read the response.json() from https://1xbet.cm/en/line/Football/1536237-FIFA-World-Cup-2018/? I get errors while trying to read this. 
I am trying to find out how you found teams_url

Comment: @jubibanna Check your browser requests you'll see all the `XHR` requests. Besides of this if this answer fills your needs, accept it.